Material shows as gray in render
I looked around if this issue is already posted but I wasn't able to find a solution.
The issue I'm having is all my textures work fine except one object and it's just one face of that object that is showing as gray. Here is are a few things I did to try fix the issue but failed.

Checking if the face has the correct normals or not
Deleting the face and extruding it again
Adding a new material to the whole object (color does change but it's so much darker and looks unnatural mostly because the box above it has the light hitting it properly)

I am new to blender so I do apologies if this is a silly question.


Link to my blender file


hello could you please share your object?

Did you check for duplicated faces?

Yeah to me that looks like duplicated faces or maybe flipped normals.

@moonboots I added a link to my blender file.

@DanielMöller I did check if there are repeating faces but there is none

@Jakemoyo I did check the normals as well, and it doesn't seem to be the issue, I updated the post to show that it's not the normals :)

The edge at the top of the front face is part of more than 2 faces, it is bad topology and creates a bad shading problem when you smooth shade, you can either right click in Object mode and Shade Flat, or, better, remove this face:


Thank you so much!
